# How to modify Django form before save?

Tags: python, django

In my project each user can have multiple enemies, like this:

**models**

```
class EnemyModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   weapon = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   related_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Only user can add enemies to his profile, so I made a form like this:

**forms**

```
class AddEnemyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EnemyModel
        exclude = ['related_user'] # only current user
```

My idea was to modify the excluded field in a view, but it doesn't work:

**views**

```
def add_enemy(request):
    args={}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddEnemyForm(request.POST)
        form.related_user = request.user # error
        # form.related_user_id = request.user.id # also error
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("<h1>Done!</h1>")
        else:
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args["form"]=form
            return render_to_response("add_enemy.html",args)
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args["form"]=AddEnemyForm()
    return render_to_response("add_enemy.html",args)
```

How to modify a form before save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `form.instance`:

```
def add_enemy(request):
    args={}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddEnemyForm(request.POST)
        # form.instance is the instance to be saved
        form.instance.related_user = request.user.userprofile
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("<h1>Done!</h1>")
        else:
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args["form"]=form
            return render_to_response("add_enemy.html",args)
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args["form"]=AddEnemyForm()
    return render_to_response("add_enemy.html",args)
```

Note that `enemymodel.related_user` should be a `UserProfile`, and `request.user` is a `User`. You need to use `request.user.userprofile`.